# Why can't we declare string like below?

Tags: java, string

What's wrong with this statement and why?

String s1 = new StringBuilder("Hello");

I think this is due to immutable String class and mutable StringBuilder class combination.
Any new suggestion/insights on this are much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? String and StringBuilder are different classes, Stringbuilder isn't a subclass of String.

Comment: They are completely different classes, and so why should a StringBuilder object be allowed to be assigned to a String variable? You first need to explain why you think that this even is possible. Does the API suggest that this might be so?

Comment: "_I think this is due to immutable String class and mutable StringBuilder class combination._" -- It's much simpler than that. A `StringBuilder` is not a `String`, and thus can't be assigned to a variable of type `String`.

Comment: You are [assigning apples to oranges](https://poemanalysis.com/idiom/apples-to-oranges)..

Comment: A `StringBuilder` is not a `String`, and using a `String` literal with `new` is an **antipattern**. `String s1 = "Hello";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"What's wrong with this statement and why?*
>
> *String s1 = new StringBuilder("Hello"); ..."*

The reason that doesn't work is because *StringBuilder* is not a subclass of *String*.

You *could*, just append the *toString* call to the *StringBuilder*.

```java
String s1 = new StringBuilder("Hello").toString();
```

Consider the following example.
The assignment will cause an error.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A value = new B();
}

class A {
    
}
    
class B {
    
}
```

On the other hand, if the objects were related, it would work.

```java
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on inheritance.
*[Inheritance (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and links shared.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the mutable / immutable properties.

Check out the [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) and the [StringBuilder API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). They each inherit directly from `Object`. Neither is a subclass of the other. So, as far as the compiler is concerned, `String s1 = new StringBuilder("Hello");` makes as much sense as `Dog fido = new Circle (4.7);`

You could have `String s1 = new StringBuilder ("Hello").toString ();`. But, that doesn't really make sense. It creates an anonymous Object, runs its `toString()` method, and then discards the StringBuilder Object. So, why not just have `String s1 = "Hello";` or `String s1 = new String ("Hello");` in the first place?

Note that `String` and `StringBuilder` each implement [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

The following code will compile:

```
    String s1 = new StringBuilder ("Hello").toString ();
    CharSequence s2 = new String (" World!");
    CharSequence s3 = new StringBuilder ("Bye");    
    s3 = s2;
    s2 = s3; 
    s2 = s1;
```

That would limit the methods of `s2` and `s3` to the methods available in`CharSequence`. If you wanted to use other methods of `String` or `StringBuilder`, you could verify the class using `instanceof`, and then a class cast.

Answer (score -2):

s1 is a String and you are using a StringBuilder to instantiate it which is a different class. Maybe something like this :

```
StingBuilder temp = new StringBuilder("Hello");
String s1 = temp.toString();
```